# How to test if gcc is installed?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc

How can I find out if I have gcc installed on my machine?

I am trying to run [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/), but it isn't responding.  I know you have to have gcc installed in order for it to work properly.
I do have Xcode 4.0.2 installed (from what I've read, if Xcode is installed then you already have gcc).

Answer (score 8):

1. Type `gcc` at the Terminal prompt. If it says "command not found", you don't. Otherwise, you do.
2. If that fails, then install from your OSX CD.

Comment: Technically, that is testing to see if gcc is in his PATH. Typing gcc could fail even if it is installed.

Comment: @objectiveGeek - Yes, but if it's not in his `$PATH` it's not going to be useful, as most scripts that rely on it being "installed" will probably rely on it also being in `$PATH` and thus callable as `gcc` instead of `/my/dumb/install/location/gcc`

Comment: @Ernest: It gave me 'no input files'.  Does this mean its installed. I'm assuming yes?

Comment: @wilis0924:  Yes.  Also try `gcc -v` to get the installed version number.

Comment: @Chris Installing `gcc` under /usr/bin is optional in Xcode’s installer.

Comment: @Drew Hall: 'version 4.2.1'  is that up to date?

Comment: @Bavarious - You can install it wherever you want, but if it's not in your `$PATH` it's going to break most outside scripts (which will expect it to be there.)

Comment: @Chris Lutz, ObjecctiveGeek is correct as this is a bad answer because it equates not finding a program with not having the program. I, for example, am having a problem where I need gcc-4.7, but synaptic is telling me I already have it, even though I don't know where it is.

Answer (score 4):

You could just try to see if a gcc executable is present. Try:

```
ls /usr/bin/gcc*
```

Comment: Better with `whereis gcc` or `which gcc`.

Comment: `which` only works if the `PATH` is correctly configured.

Comment: Yet, if you don't have `/usr/bin` in your `PATH`, your Mac OS is likely to be broken.

Comment: If someone messed up the `.bash_profile` for the particular user, the `PATH` could be messed up while the system is ok.

Comment: I, for one, have gcc-4.7-base installed (according to synaptic package manager) but `whereis`/`which` can not find it

Answer (score 3):

You can use "locate gcc" to find all filenames with gcc in them.

Answer (score 3):

Try any terminal command, like:

```
$ gcc --help
```

If gcc isn't installed, you will often see a message with a "how to install it" note, complete with the package manager's command.

Answer (score 0):

On Terminal type

```
gcc -v
```

You will get something like below

```
Using built-in specs.
 ......
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

This will show you version of GCC installed on your machine. If gcc is not installed then this command will not work as above

Comment: Can you add some more explanation of what this output means.

Comment: Please check edited part